# How can I change a select option value when I change the value of another select option in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to change a select option value when I change the value of another select option in AngularJS. When I tried to do this on W3schools.com it worked, but in my development, it doesn't. The working code I tested is [available here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD084OYCQJ6U). https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD084OYCQJ6U

This is my AngularJS JavaScript.
Model is like this:

```
$scope.modelCountry = [ { ID : 1, Name : 'Philippines'}, { ID : 2, Name : 'United States'} ];
$scope.changeCountry = function (stateID) {
  if (stateID == 1) {
    //$scope.CountryName = "Philippines";
    return 'Philippines';
  }
  else if (stateID > 1) {
    //$scope.CountryName = "US United States";
    return 'United States';
  }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 padding-top-5px"><!--State-->
  <div class="col-md-2"><span class="pull-right">State <b>*</b></span></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.Name for state in modelState" ng-change="selectedCountryName=changeCountry(selectedState.ID)">
      <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div><!-- End State-->
<div class="col-md-12 padding-top-5px"><!--Location-->
  <div class="col-md-2"><span class="pull-right">Country <b>*</b></span></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCountryName" ng-options="country.Name for country in modelCountry">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div><!-- End Location-->
```

Comment: @Saiyaff Farouk: Be aware, when you edit posts, not to skip lines!!! I re-added it from review queue.

Comment: My bad. @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but one of the normal use case of double `select` is changing the option list of second `select` when user change the selection of first `select`, as example below.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.types = [
    { id: 1, name: 'fruits' },
    { id: 2, name: 'vehicles' }
  ]
  
  var fruits = [
    { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
    { id: 2, name: 'banana' },
    { id: 3, name: 'orange' }
  ]
  
  var vehicles = [
    { id: 4, name: 'car' },
    { id: 5, name: 'bus' },
    { id: 6, name: 'lorry' }
  ]
  
  $scope.changeType = function() {
    $scope.selectedItem = 0;
  
    if ($scope.selectedType == 1) {
      $scope.items = fruits;
    }
    else if ($scope.selectedType == 2) {
      $scope.items = vehicles;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <select ng-model='selectedType' 
          ng-options='type.id as type.name for type in types' 
          ng-change='changeType()'>
          
    <option value="">Select type</option>        
  </select>
  
  <select ng-model='selectedItem' 
          ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in items'>
          
      <option value="">Select item</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it's like the one you do but to be specific. The one I am trying to do is like when you select the 'Vehicles' it should change to select 'Car' and when select fruits it would change to select 'apple only'. Please help I still testing it using your code. I modified it but not working here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDCX0H6WIEC8 Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDD1G7707HLP
The code is using `id` as the identifiers, so assigning the `id` of the items will do.